# Reg expression matches behavior, exclude value?

Tags: c#, regex

I have test string

```
var test = "test[2][3][4]";
```

I need to extract integers from it - 2, 3, 4

I have such code

```
    var regex = new Regex(@"\[(\d)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    var matches = regex.Matches(test);
```

which return me these values

```
matches[0].Groups[0].Value = "[2]"
matches[0].Groups[1].Value = "2
```

I do not really need `[2]`, but I do not know what to change in order to exclude it? If I understand correctly the capture group `(\d)` should capture only digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always an implicit "0th" capturing group that gets populated with what the expression as a whole matched. Normally you should just ignore it.

If you *really* want to not get back duplicate information (which is only good for an intellectual exercise), you can transform the regex to this:

```
@"(?<=\[)\d(?=\])"
```

Using positive and negative lookbehind, you can assert that your digit is surrounded by square brackets without actually capturing them. This way `matches[0]` will be just what you want. There will be no `matches[1]` since there is no capturing group in the expression above.

But again, as a practical matter just ignore `matches[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why regex? =)

You can do like this:

```
var test = "test[2][3][4]";
var numbers = test.Where(Char.IsDigit)
                  .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()))
                  .ToArray();
//Numbers will now be a array with the integers : 2,3,4
//numers[0] = 2
//numers[1] = 3
//numers[2] = 4
```

Comment: If we are talking about single digit then `int.Parse(c.ToString())` better replace with `c - '0'`

Answer (score 0):

The first match group always contains the entire match, and there's nothing you can do about it.

> If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element
>   of the GroupCollection object returned by the Groups property contains
>   a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern.
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)

As you can see in the example on that page, you can just start at matches[0].Groups[1] to start with the first capture group.